# Keep image size if the path is wrong

Tags: html, css, image

I want to show an empty square if the path of the image is wrong, but I want the not-existing image to have a specific size.  I have tried like this, but the browser shows the default not-existing image size. How could I do it?

```css
.clsSize {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img src="wrong-path.jpg" class="clsSize" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" width="100" height="100">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a bit of JavaScript to make this work out. Images have an event fired called `onError` when the image cannot be loaded, which you can make use of. I believe this should be used only on HTTP protocol, but may or may not work on the file protocols.

With jQuery, the code looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('img').error(function () {
    $(this).attr('src', 'missing.png');
  });
});
```

And in vanilla JavaScript, it's:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++)
  imgs[0].onerror = function () {
    this.src = "missing.png";
  };
```

**Working Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $('img').error(function () {
    $(this).attr({
      'src': 'https://i.imgur.com/9q6NxKo.png',
      "width": 100
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<img src="hello.png" />
```

I have created a huge blog article, explaining the way and demo too. You can have a look at [Handling Broken Image Links in a Better Way](https://blog.praveen.science/handling-broken-image-links-in-a-better-way-http-only/).

I am not sure if this can be achieved without JavaScript or a server side language.